# BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`

Tags: windows-10, npm

It takes me lots of time doing uninstalling and reinstalling angular-cli but all of this is not luck it keeps giving me this error

```
**[ng] BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist**
```

Comment: The error string is a Linux command: this will not work in Windows, though it may be possible if you install EXE ports of `dirname` and `sed` and these are accessible through your `PATH` variable; or you could try installing under Windows Subsystem for Linux, but you would then also need to run the application under WSL. Have you searched for a Windows port of your application?